# IF statement evaluating bit from php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bit

I have a form posting to a script. Sometimes there is a value on the form called `stat`. Here is how I handle it:

```
$data['stat'] = isset($_POST['stat']) ? true : false;
echo "STAT VALUE: " . var_dump($data['stat']);
```

The output (I am currently testing a `false` response:

```
bool(false) STAT VALUE:
```

My relevant SQL to evaluate this value:

```
@stat               bit
-- Inserted some data
if @stat = 1
    DECLARE @NewConsultId int
    SELECT @NewConsultId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    EXEC insertFacilityDecision @NewConsultId, 'EMERGENCY REQUEST', NULL, 17
```

What is happening is my `insertFacilityDecision` stored procedure is always being called, even though `false` values are being passed to the stored procedure.

Am I evaluating a bit incorrectly?

Comment: I think you forgot begin/end

Comment: You didn't think indenting guides SQL Server on control of flow, did you?

Comment: No. It was for ease of reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose into `begin ... end` statements supposed to be executed on `if` condition

```
if @stat = 1
begin
    DECLARE @NewConsultId int
    SELECT @NewConsultId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    EXEC insertFacilityDecision @NewConsultId, 'EMERGENCY REQUEST', NULL, 17
end
```

`begin end` can be ommited for single command only, so in your case it was:

```
if @stat = 1
    DECLARE @NewConsultId int -- this statement is under condition

-- two below are not
SELECT @NewConsultId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
EXEC insertFacilityDecision @NewConsultId, 'EMERGENCY REQUEST', NULL, 17
```